# How can I fix a GCM 'Permission Denied' error

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, server

I am using PHP to build a GCM-based application in Android, but when I try to connect to the server,  it is returning the below error:

```
Curl failed: Failed to connect to 64.233.183.95: Permission denied<br/>
```

What steps can I take to solve this issue?
I'm using PHP for getting the registration ID from an Android device to the GCM service.

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }



        // then call this method
        $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);
        $message = array("msg" => "txt_message");

        $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

        echo $result;
```

Comment: You need to connect over SSL, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Change `http` to `https` :

> To send a message, the application server issues a POST request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send.

([Source](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html))

Comment: thanks for response, i tried this but there is return same error